# nginx server_name regex capture not getting substituted in ssl_certificate

Tags: regex, nginx, config

I am trying the following:

```
server_name ~^domain\.(?<tld>.*)$;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ssl-chain-domain-$tld.pem;
```

I am getting:

[emerg] 22812#22812: BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/private/ssl-chain-domain-$tld.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/private/ssl-chain-domain-$tld.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

Obviously, not var substitution is happening. $1 does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html):

> Variables should not be used as template macros. Variables are evaluated in the run-time during the processing of each request

In other words: Nginx doesn't load the certificate separately for each request, so variables won't be used for that. You need to ender your specific certificate paths explicitly.

Also, this question probably belongs on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) (but I don't know how to move it).

Comment: That explains it. Anyway, I went with a single certificate for all domains of the virtual server, thereby eliminating the need for the variable.

Comment: Now we can, since version 1.15.9: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate